# vba returning data validation list items and item index

Tags: vba, list, validation

I have a cell which contains data validation with following formula

> =IF($E10<>"";INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($E10;"-";"_"));INDIRECT("Errorlist"))

I am trying to get the elements in that list so I could compare it to the elements in that list and return the index of the selected item in that list
Here is a part of the code I am using. I am getting an error on the set of rngTest..

```
Dim wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim AlldataWB As Workbook
    Dim rngTest As range
    Dim cell As range

    Set AlldataWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks2 = AlldataWB.Sheets("MA")

    Set cell = wks2.range(wks2.Cells(10, 8), wks2.Cells(10, 8))

    Set rngTest = cell.Validation.Formula1
```

Any help would be appreciated!